# Permissions not showing when installing generated APK

Tags: android, apk, sony-xperia

I have an issue where I can't install the APK.
I have built an APK in Android Studio and sent it to a user.
However, the user is unable to install the APK, it reaches the screen where it shows the list of permissions, but none of the permissions is displayed (empty screen with "Cancel" and "Next" options) and the user can't click on next as well.

However, the user was able to install a generated APK with none permission (comment out all the permissions), and this issue specific to "Sony X F5121" with the latest Android OS.

List of permissions used by my App.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <permission
        android:name="lb.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="lb.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <!-- Google Maps Stuff -->
    <permission
        android:name="lb.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="lb.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

1- Why permission not showing up.

2- Why user unable to install

Comment: Which is your target SDK?

Comment: @Ivan The App setting as follow
`compileSdkVersion 25`
`buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'`
`minSdkVersion 16`
`targetSdkVersion 21`

Answer (score 0):

in which Android device you are running you app..?

**Beginning in Android 6.0** (**API level 23**), users **grant permissions** to apps while the **app is running**, **not when they install the app**. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

Comment: afaik, what you say is true, but the permissions are showed at the installation time although you have to grant then in runtime. So the user knows which permissions are going to be asked.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, as I mentioned the issue is specific to "Sony X", I have no issue with installing the APK on Nexus 5 and Samsung, where both of them are using Android API 23.
However, if you are saying I don't need the permissions in the "Manifest" file, what about the lower Android API levels as my app minimum SDK 16?

Thanks

Comment: @Aziz  as per doc if your app in targeting ** Android 6.0 or >* than your need to ask permission at the run time not while installing if your app in rub below  Android 6.0 than all permission are grant by default

Comment: @NileshRathod the problem hes facing is not about the permissions in runtime or installation time, is about installing the app. He can't install the app in that specific device. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ivan Yep that's true, the main issue is the user reaches the permissions screen but they are not displayed (empty screen) and the user cannot click "Next" to complete the installation. The issue is specific to "Sony X F5121".